# QT : "this file is not part of any project"

Tags: qt-creator

[image]

I created a project folder (test1), then when creating the C++ source file main.cpp, it says that this file is not part of any project although i created it in the same project test1 by doing :
File -> new file or project -> C++ -> C++ source file.

Comment: I have the same problem, and our project uses CMake... so it's not a .pro problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open the .pro file and check if something like this is missing:

```
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

(with proper path if needed)

Also it seems you did not configure the project. In "projects" you should choose a kit to use when building. This may also be a cause of the warning.

Answer (score 0):

For a `.creator` project (without Qmake) deleting the `.creator.user` file while Qt Creator is closed helped in my case.